# How to build and deploy xamarin-evolve locally in android device

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm brand new to xamarin world (as well as visual studio). I've forked xamarin-evolve app [1](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve/) and trying to build and deploy in my local android device.

In documentation, under "Mobile App" section, its mentioned:

> Simply restore your NuGet packages and build the application.

As a beginner, I'm looking for a bit more explanation how to build and deploy this project locally in my android device. So that I can play with it.

I would truly appreciate any cooperation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you Open up `src/XamarinEvolve.sln`, do the dollowing steps :

1. Clean the project solution.
2. Delete the `bin` & `obj` folder in `XamarinEvolve.Android`, `XamarinEvolve.iOS`  and `XamarinEvolve.UWP`.
3. Right click on your `Project Solution`, then click the `Restore NuGet packages`.
4. Deploy the `XamarinEvolve.Android` project in your device.

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMF5N.png).